# Error when hosting site, which does not appear when put on localhost

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to upload a website that I made using cakephp 3.5.10. The site is running normally on my PC, the problem is when I try to put it online in the hostgator, which gives this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home/jessica059/public_html/site.net.br/areadocliente/webroot/index.php on line 33
```

index.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * The Front Controller for handling every request
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (https://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          https://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since         0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */

// Check platform requirements
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/requirements.php';

// For built-in server
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/' . basename(__FILE__);

    $url = parse_url(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $file = __DIR__ . $url['path'];
    if (strpos($url['path'], '..') === false && strpos($url['path'], '.') !== false && is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    }
}
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Application;
use Cake\Http\Server;

// Bind your application to the server.
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));

// Run the request/response through the application and emit the response.
$server->emit($server->run());
```

I took a look at Hostgator's CPanel and the php version that was there was 3.2 so I changed it to 3.6, updated the site page and even then the error continues.

I'm completely lost as it's my first time putting up a website online.

I apologize for any mistake in English.

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp version 3.5.10 requires PHP 5.6.0 or greater